# Rename folder in active directory with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a powershell script to change the User home folder name to some "NewName" but it is not working for me. Here is my code:

```
$NewHomeDirectory = "\\SRV10177\users001$\newusername"
Get-ADuser -Identity $OldUserName | Set-ADUser -HomeDirectory $NewHomeDirectory
```

Later I also tried this code:

```
Rename-Item -path \\SRV10177\users001$\Oldusername -newName \\SRV10177\users001$\Newusername
```

But the folder name still not changed.

Would be great if someone can tell me what am I doing wrong in this case?

**EDIT**

After outputting the rename-item command I got this:

```
Rename-Item : Access to the path '\\SRV10177\Users000$\newusername' is denied.
At C:\folder_rename\folder_rename_action.ps1:202 char:9
+         Rename-Item -path $OldHomeDirectory -newName $NewHomeDirector ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (\\SRV10177\Users000$\newusername:Str 
   ing) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands. 
   RenameItemCommand
```

**EDIT.2**
Ok, so it was related to the permissions that require to make changes. After having it everything worked as it suppose to.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of observations:

1) Your error is showing for *\SRV10177* while you have mentioned the path as *\srv1011*

2) It is stating clearly that you do not have the permission to access the path or the path is invalid so it is not able to access that.

Lets consider you have a valid path which you can always check using *Test-Path*, then you should try running the *powershell as administrator*.

Second, try giving a different share path and see if at all its a permission issue. may be you do not have the right to access/modify that.

Hope it helps.